# How to have always a different variable chosen in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What do I need to add to the following code, so that a different variable is chosen each time and not the same letter occurs after itself.

goal is a situation like this:

after pressing `run`: change = a

after pressing `run` second time: change = b

after pressing `run` third time: change = a

after pressing `run` for the fourth time: change = c

after pressing `run` for the fifth time: change = b

...

```js
var ch = ['a', 'b', 'c']
change = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = ch[Math.floor(Math.random() * ch.length)];
```

```html
<label id="1"> </label>
```

Comment: It seems to work?  I get 'a' sometimes and 'b' sometimes.

Comment: This logic only runs once.  There is no "each time".  It's unclear what your issue is.  Please make an [mcve] of the issue

Comment: Do you mean that you want to exclude the possibility of having the same character being consecutively selected whenever you run the script again?

Comment: exactly @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Currently a character is selected only when you re-run the JavaScript (aka refresh page). Is this representative of the real scenario? Or is the selection made within the same page without re-running the JavaScript? The latter one is a lot easier to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a system where you remove the character from the list after it has been selected. This way, when you call the random select function again you won't be able to select the same value twice in a row.

However you do need to save the item you've selected somewhere in a variable so that you're able to add it back to the list once a new character has been chosen.

The snippet below demonstrates this principle. Try it out and follow the annotations to figure out the logic. It even works when you add more options. No chances of the same consecutive results.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const button = document.getElementById('select');

// Available options.
const options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// Previously selected option.
let selectedOption = null;

// Function which selects a random item from
// the options array.
const selectRandomOption = () => {
  // Get a random index and select the option.
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
  const option = options[index];
  
  // If there is a previous selected option..
  if (selectedOption !== null) {
    // ..then add it back to the list.
    options.push(selectedOption);
  }
  
  // Store the newly selected option..
  selectedOption = option;
  
  // ..and remove it from the list so it cannot
  // be selected again until the next time 
  // selectRandomOption is called.
  options.splice(index, 1);
  
  // Return the selected option.
  return option;
};

// Trigger the selectRandomOption when clicking
// on the button and show the result in the output.
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const option = selectRandomOption();
  output.value = option;
});
```

```html
<output id="output"> </output>
<button id="select">Select random but not the same</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is called a "toggle" functionality.
You can achieve that with the following code:

```js
var span = document.getElementById("value");
span.innerHTML = 'on';

function toggle(){
    span.innerHTML = (span.innerHTML == 'on' ? 'off' : 'on');
}
```

```html
<p>
  value: <span id="value"></span>
</p>
<button onClick="toggle()"> click me </button>
```

Comment: This works for 2 variables but what if there are 3 or more variables?

Comment: Take your time to re-write your post, because it's not clear what you really need

Comment: Your question only asks for a toggle-behavior though, not cycling through a list of options. This answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: @SavePain, your question illustrates a need for only 2 different values. The problem space is different when you introduce new variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the value from index once its been used

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*ch.length);
change = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = ch[rand];
ch.splice(rand,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this as a toggle between `a` and `b`.  Code below does that.

```js
let displayDiv = document.getElementById("result");
let [a,b] = ['a','b'];

//one-liner swap & display
toggle = () => {
   displayDiv.innerText = ([a,b] = [b,a])[0];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Run</button>
<div id="result">a</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To cycle through a list of options, you can use `Array.shift()` and re-insert the previous content of the output-element back into the array.

```js
let options = ["B", "C", "D", "E"];
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let output = document.querySelector("#output");
  options.push(output.innerHTML);
  output.innerHTML = options.shift();
});
```

```html
<span id="output">A</span>
<button>New value</button>
```

To select a random value of a list, randomize the selection using `Math.random()`, and save the content of the HTML-element back inside the array. Then, remove that array-element and set the HTML-element's content to that value.

```js
let options = ["B", "C", "D", "E"];
let output = document.querySelector("#output");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  options.push(output.innerHTML);
  let newValue = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
  output.innerHTML = newValue;
  options.splice(options.indexOf(newValue), 1);
});
```

```html
<span id="output">A</span>
<button>New value</button>
```